R Indicate Functions in Source File
In R, suppose that I have a first file my_source.R, which contains a function :
#my_source.R

foo <- function(){
    ...
}

In another file main.R, I want to use the function foo. I would write :
#main.R

source("my_source.R")

foo()

The problem I am facing is that, when there are too many source files and too many functions, whereas each source file contains several functions, my teammates tell me that they have trouble finding the referenced function. That is, in this example, they claim to have difficulty tracking down that foo comes from my_source.R when they are looking at main.R.
Therefore, I am now looking for a way to indicate in my code that the function foo comes from my_source.R. That is, something similar to "my_source.R"::foo. Is there a way to achieve this?

Yes, wrap your functions and their wrappers in a small package.

So I have to wrap them up into packages ? I guess as much.

A single one should be enough.

A vastly better solution is to use ‘box’, which allows you to write modules as you’re used from other programming languages, and you can (and by default will) fully qualify the module name, giving you pretty much exactly what you want.

If each R function were in a separate file whose name is the name of the function then the name of the function would also be sufficient identify the file.

I agree that just creating an R package for all your functions is the easiest way to share them. You could choose to give all the functions from one file a common prefix to make it easier to look up. You could also explicitly load your functions in a custom environment. Then you could do
my_source <- new.env()
source("my_source.R", local=my_source)
my_source$foo()

After you load data into R, as long as the "keep.source" options is set to TRUE, you can get the the file an imported function name from with
getSrcFilename(my_source$foo)

But that's at runtime. It wouldn't be helpful if you were just looking at code
